# Tomcat8/Spring5 deploy fails

Tags: spring, maven, spring-security, spring-data, tomcat8

I'm trying to migrate my code from Spring4 to Spring5 and already did refactor to match the 5's API, but when I try to deploy the app, there's this error coming:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.unwrapOptional(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

I alreaday checked the dependency:tree and there are no old (Spring 4's) libraries.

I use Tomcat 8.0.32 on Ubuntu.

Anyone could tell me what I'm missing here?

The dep tree is available [here](https://pastebin.com/cBry3bDU).

Full log with stack trace [here](https://pastebin.com/7yg2N9rS).

Comment: Please post a listing of your webapp's `WEB-INF/lib` directory. Also, post content here, not links to content somewhere else.

Comment: @BoristheSpider You're right, there are some old entries... -> https://pastebin.com/P5TanM4A
Should just delete these?

Comment: No, of course not. You need to work out where they come from. Also, see earlier comment about not posting link. I'm not visiting random pastebin links - so there is a limited extent to which I can help.

Comment: OK, sorry for that! But I found out that I just simply did not do mvn clean before switching to new libs. After that, it worked. Embarassing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't run `mvn clean` and there were still old Spring libraries in the classpath...